# VS Code says "Permission denied" when trying to run active file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I tried searching for a solution but haven't found one.

I have a folder on my desktop called "Code".

I have my HTML file and JS file within. The folder and the file are set to full access. I even ran VS Code as admin but still getting the same error.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Did you also restart your computer?

Comment: What does "run active file" mean?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: running osx 10.13.6. I have restarted the computer since installing the program, and after receiving the error.  Nothing was showing up in chrome so I tried to go to Terminal > Run Active File in Visual Studio to see if that would do anything but still nothing. Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/1jcizUB

Answer (score 2):

Change file permission: chmod u+x *program_name*